# convert html characters back to text in Flash - AS3

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-3, htmlspecialchars

I need to generate an editable xml file to supply content to a flash website.

I am generating my file with a html form, and `htmlspecialchars` e.g.:

```
    $currentItem = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($currentItem));
```

This is to prevent xml entries which would produce the error **"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed"**, such as

```
<entry title="Words & Things">
---------------------^
```

It has the side effect of making the flash file display the html codes for the content, rather than the proper characters.

Is there a good way to convert the codes back, once they are read into the Flash file (as3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
public function htmlUnescape(str:String):String
{
    return new XMLDocument(str).firstChild.nodeValue;
}
```

(Found at:  http://www.razorberry.com/blog/archives/2007/11/02/converting-html-entities-in-as3/)

Comment: Tidy! Thanks Ryan not had chance to check it yet but this should work a treat I'm sure.

Answer (score -2):

Use `html_entity_decode`: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: I think he's looking for a way to do it inside the flash once he has the XML loaded.